# iPhone sends notifications to another iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have two iphones that use the same apple ID. Calls to one phone now ring on both phones at the same time and notifications are sent to just one - meaning iphone A gets notifications for iphoen A and iphone B. Other than signing out of the same icloud account, is there a way to disconnect the phones so notifications and call going to iphone B will go to it and not iphone A, and vice versa?

Comment: What is the toggle position in Settings > Phone > Calls on Other Devices > Allow Calls on Other Devices

Comment: @AivarPaalberg - thanks, turned it off for both devices. Now, what about Notifications? Can I do the same with that so devices will use their own push tokens and not share notifications?